# Resharper cannot handle Null-condition "To condition expression" in scope while Nullable-digit member related?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, resharper

I have found a strange issue with Resharper Ultimate 2018.1.
Look the code below(c#):

```
int? a = 1;
var b = a == 1 ? "1" : "2";
var c = b?.Length;
```

When I try to use Resharper quick-fix  to convert **?.** to normal null condition in file/project/solution scope, it keeps applying forever:

[image]
[image]

But if I change

```
int? a = 1;
```

to

```
int a = 1;
```

or just fix the single line not in scope,it will finish immediately.

Will this happen in your develop environment?
Is this a bug with Resharper?

I have posted the issue to Resharper bugtracker.
https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-469860

Comment: I am not sure why would you want that version instead, but I would suggest you to post this as a bug on the ReSharper website. There's probably nothing the community can do here

Comment: With your code, `b` will never be null. it will be either 1 or 2 based on the value of `a`. But at the same time `a` is nullable and you are not checking `a` for null to decide what should be assigned to `b`. May be you can try `var b = a == null ? null : a == 1 ? "1" : "2";`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya It doesn't actually matter whether `b` can logically be `null` or not, because at compile time it certainly *can* be, since it's a reference type. I also wouldn't think too deeply about the most basic example needed to reproduce the issue

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I have simplied the question, acctually the nullable "a" variable, in my solution ,represented as a nullable property of a class.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Thanks .The background reason of doing this, is that I want to change some c# 6 code to c# 4.

Comment: If you translate `var c = b?.Length` to conditional expression  it results in `var c = b == null ? null ? b.Length` and that results in compile time error 'Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between '<null>' and 'int'` May be because of this Resharper gets confused and try to avoid the errors and challenges it's own decision.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Resharper will translate the statement to `var c = b != null ? b.Length : (int?) null;`  in the single line.Seems it went something wrong in scope processing.

Comment: @eforlina please use Resharper's bugtracker for reporting possible bugs: https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/RSRP